# MyBatis - Mapper vs DAO

Tags: java, sql, dao, datamapper, mybatis

I am trying to get this answered, and found one comment in the MyBatis documentation:

> Usually `MapperFactoryBean` is preferred to this class, since it
>   requires no extra code. But, this class(`DAO`) is useful if you need to do
>   other non-MyBatis work in your `DAO` and concrete classes are required and use `SqlSessionDaoSupport` or `SqlSessionFactory`

In case I chose to use `MapperFactoryBean` today in my project, but later I would need to use `concrete DAO` (may be because you may not do 100% using SQLs in mapper), then I need to change the design.

If the above is true, then MapperFactoryBean would be very less useful and would never(or mostly) be a choice.

In other words: Can MapperFactoryBean and DAO co-exists? Even if yes, should they be?

Comment: Why are you thinking this? And what is your question?

Comment: My Questions is: In case I am using a Mapper, and I would need to create some dynamic SQL (which may me outside of MyBatis Support), I would end up using DAO. So why not use DAO as design choice at first place even you have a slight chances of having the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of what this *"non-MyBatis work"* or *"some dynamic SQL"* how you call it exactly is? Well I'm not. But assuming writing Mappers is much faster and more intuitive for your developers you are saving a lot of time here. And when there are some scary non-MyBatis things to do why not writing then a very specific DAO which only does this one non-MyBatis thing?

Comment: Why not write DAO(in case you want a scary non-MyBatis) is that I need to change the whole service to change to DAO instead of existng mapper.

Comment: @SandeepJindal No what I'm saying is that both can exist next to each other.

Comment: Right, probably, this is the right question: "Can MapperFactoryBean and DAO co-exists? Even if yes, should they be?" I have updated the question also.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for coexistence ( DAO is not a must ! ) This is especially true if you are using mybatis in spring framework.

As for the refactoring part, it's good if you have incorpoproate a suitable testing framework to help out.